# disk usage issue with rsync and --link-dest

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, rsync

I have disk usage problem with `rsync` and `--link-dest`
Incremental backup is taking full disk space:

```
@localhost media]$ ls
orig
----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ du -sh .
25M .
----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ rsync -avh orig/ full
----------------------------------------------------
@localhost media]$ du -sh .
49M .
----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ echo 1111 > orig/foo111
----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ rsync -avh --link-dest=full orig/ orig_1
----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ ls orig_1/foo111 
orig_1/foo111
_____________________________________________________

localhost media]$ ls full/foo111
ls: cannot access full/foo111: No such file or directory
```

Everything looks good so far. The latest change is reflected in `orig_1`
But the directories aren't hard linked and they're all in full size.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ du -sh .
74M .
---------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ du -sh orig_1/
25M orig_1/
--------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ du -sh orig
25M orig
---------------------------------------------
localhost media]$ du -sh full
25M full
```

Am I suppose to have the `orig_1` size as 0? And `stat` command shows no hard links. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unix doesn't allow hard links to directories.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 24):

When you ran `rsync -avh --link-dest=full orig/ orig_1`, you ignored this error message (it's more obvious if you remove `-v`):

```
--link-dest arg does not exist: full
```

If we then take a look at `man rsync` under `--link-dest`, we find:

```
If DIR is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.
```

And there it is. `full` is relative to the current directory. Relative to the destination directory, it would be `../full`.

If you try again with `rsync -avh --link-dest=../full orig/ orig_1`, you get what you expect:

```
$ du -sh *
149M    full
149M    orig
232K    orig_1
$ du -sh .
298M    .
```

Note that, when counted individually, the directories still appear take up the full space:

```
$ du -sh orig_1 
149M    orig_1
```

This is because `du` keeps track of files it's already seen, and avoids counting them twice.

Comment: You are awesome :) , Gracious. I owe you lunch :).

Comment: Please help me with other question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298652/incremental-backup-with-rsync-backup-backup-dir-not-working?noredirect=1#comment32098494_21298652

Comment: If you liked this answer, it would be helpful for everyone that you marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

`--link-dest` takes a path relative to the destination. You want `--link-dest=../orig`.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Unix filesystems do not allow hard links to directories, except for the special `.` and `..` links. `--link-dest` only creates hard links for files, the rest of the directory structure is recreated as real directories.

And even if hard links were allowed to directories, `du` would still show the full size of each link. When using hard links, there's no distinction between the original and the link, they're each just names that refer to a particular inode, and `du` would scan them equivalently.

Comment: as per the rsync manual, I am not suppose to have that extra 25M disk usage when I use the --link-dest, df command is showing that I have another full copy.

Comment: Use `df`, not `du`, to get actual disk usage. `du` doesn't know about the duplication.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wrong, `du` _does_ avoid double-counting hard links.

Comment: BEFORE

This is the df before
localhost media]$ df /
Filesystem              1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  16874332 6835520   9174968  43% /

localhost media]$ rsync -avh orig/ full

localhost media]$ rsync -avh --link-dest=full orig/ orig_1

AFTER

localhost media]$ df /
Filesystem              1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  16874332 6891196   9119292  44% /

6891196 - 6835520 = 55M ( full directory is full copy which is taking 25M, dont know why orig_1 also taking another 25M ? )

Comment: `--link-dest` only creates hard links for unchanged files. But since `orig_1` is a new directory, there are no unchanged files. Maybe you need to use `--compare-dest` to use `full` for the comparison.

Comment: stat orig_1/idmapd.conf 
  File: ‘orig_1/idmapd.conf’
  Size: 3580       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d Inode: 941342      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   durga)   Gid: ( 1000/   durga)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2014-01-22 18:55:54.777923226 -0800
Modify: 2014-01-22 13:34:42.000000000 -0800
Change: 2014-01-22 18:55:54.777923226 -0800
 Birth: -

Comment: I can't read those unformatted comments. Why are you bothering, I already said that `du` doesn't double-count hard links.

Comment: localhost media]$ rsync -avh --compare-dest=full/ orig/ orig_1  resulted in the same output

Comment: sorry about the unformatted comments, it is not allowing me to have new line :(

Comment: I know you can't put newlines in comments. So don't try to put code that needs formatting in comments, add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new user and cannot answer my question within 8 hours.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you ask on the correct site. I noticed you posted another, very similar question here. Try unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com, they're better for system administration help.